# update div with jquery on ajax call without refreshing the page

Tags: ajax, jquery

can anyone help please. I have a problem updating "div" inside of "table" to update "tr with_id". However when I run test and 
place  without_"id" outside of table my script runs greate and i'm getting server "TEST" response

```
<table style="border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #2F2E2F;">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Notifications</th>
    </tr>

  <div id="update_118">
  <tr class="read_118">
  </div>

<td>... </td>
<td><a href="http://www.hamayk.com/photos/show/156"> Comment on your Photo </a></td>
<td>today 21:43</td>
<td>... </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to up update this "div" when mouseover on success: function() without page refreshing to have its value change to class="light" to have NOT TO CALL ajax  url: "/alerts/ajax_read/118" over and over while mouse is over on it.

```
<div id="update_118">
<tr class="light">
</div>
```

here is my script,...

```
<script>     
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.read_118').on('mouseover', function(){

         var id = $(this).attr("id")
         var data = 'id=' + id ;

            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/alerts/ajax_read/118",
            data: data,                    
            cache: false,     

    success: function(){    
 $('#update_118').fadeOut('slow').load('/alerts/ajax_load/118').fadeIn("slow");
 return false;

            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

here is my server response file:

```
  $response = " <tr class='light'> ";
         echo $response;
```

thanks in advance,... 
chris

Comment: What's your question? What's happening instead of what you want? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no there is no error @Barmar,... I just want to update div with class='light' when ajax call is made e.g. /alerts/ajax_read/118 to have database table field to set 1,... (originally is set to 0) this function is works,... all it needs to update div on success with /alerts/ajax_load/118 where I have echo $response;

Comment: It looks like it should work, what's it doing instead? Is the /alerts/ajax_load/118 AJAX call happening? If you put an alert in the success function, does it work? Do you see it succeeding in the Network tab of the inspector?

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid, you can't have a DIV as a child of TABLE. You're also missing the closing `</tr>`.

Comment: /alerts/ajax_load/118 is working when I have update div outside of table,... </tr> is at the end of page right before script start,... well you're right,... I can't have div as a child inside TABLE,... how else can I do this,...? thanks

Comment: HTML elements have to be nested properly. You can't have `<tr>` inside a `<div>` and the matching `</tr>` after the `</div>`. Your table is not constructed properly.

Comment: thanks Barman,... I got all fixed,... I put everything in <div> and removed TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Update following line

```
success: function(){
```

To

```
success: function(data){
```

and set the "data" variable value to your respective "div" or other place where you want.